# Stateless Functional Component - React

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am new to React and I am doing some tutorials online. 
Now I have task like this: 
*If the  Component in the following code is a Stateless Functional Component, what expression would you write to access the items prop inside the Component?*

```
<IngredientList items={ingredient.items} />
```

I have no idea what is correct answer and why :/
Would you be so kind to help me ?

Comment: A stateless functional component is what is sounds like. You get access to props as-is. So your answer is props.items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's stateless `props.items`. If its a class `this.props.items`

Stateless functional components typically look something like this.

Passing just a single prop to a child would like this.

```
const ChildComponent = ({ someProp }) => (
   <div>
      <h1>Child Component {someProp}</h1>
   </div>
)
```

Passing all of the parents props to a child would like like this.

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => (
   <div>
      <h1>Child Component {props.someProp}</h1>
   </div>
)
```

Comment: Great! Thank you a lot! :)

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can access all your props by using props.itemName.
Ex:

By simply typing props.items

Answer (score 0):

Your functional component will look something like below,

```
const IngredientList = props => {
  // here you get all the props passed to IngredientList
  const items = props.items.map(item => <div>item</div>);

  return <div>items</div>
}
```